# Akka throttle cost function for dynamic congestion control?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm a total Scala noob, and trying to get my mind around the best way to implement what I'm thinking of.

I have a `Sink` that emits rows from a database and a `Flow` that sends a batch query to the database to delete those rows.

I want to leverage a TCP Slow Start-esque function to grow and contract the number of rows sent in each request whenever one of my queries takes too long. For example if the query took 25ms I would halve the bulk delete window size and begin probing upward until receiving another timeout.

`throttle`'s cost function seems pretty well suited to this. I could wrap my query function to time each execution and then update my summary statistics. However, it also indicates that I know a fixed cost budget I want to target. So I'm very unsure about using it in this case and I don't know the caveats around using `throttle` which there seem to be some. It seems like it would be difficult to grow and contract the "window" size for how many rows I want to try deleting at once.

Also, sounded like `Actor` interop with `ask` might be good as the `Actor` can hold the state of the window size and I could reshape that size after getting a "timeout".

Does something like this exist already?

Comment: I'd consider sending your DB delete rows through a `groupedWithin` flow which takes a batch size and a time period. Keeping the time period constant you can vary the batch size with the time it takes to write each batch.